# Setting up website with one domain name and two servers

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, wordpress

Forgive me if this has already been answered, but I have looked everywhere.

Basically, we have a store setup on a windows server. However, we want to setup a second area within the website for content and articles, etc.. We want to setup the content area to be a wordpress site on a linux server. How can we configure IIS on the windows server and apache/wordpress on the other server to accomplish this task while using the same domain name?

We want the URLs to look like the following.

http://www.store.com/
http://www.store.com/articles/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may disagree with the order in which I would do things.

The easiest thing in the long run would be to just run PHP on the Windows box, and use the Linux server for something else -- WordPress works absolutely fine, though you may need to install an ISAPI filter for URL rewrites if you want SEO-friendly URLs. The second-easiest  would be to give a DNS subdomain, like blog.mydomain.com, to the WordPress site on the Apache host, and access the blog using that. The third-easiest thing would be to do some kind of mod_proxy reverse proxying from the Apache host to the IIS host, but this introduces the proxy as a single point of failure for the entire operation.